# Get data from list in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `list` as given below with hard coded data records. Now I want to perform some functions on this list which would return most senior and junior students and a method which would return the roll no. of all students and lastly, a method which returns the students where `FirstName="ali"`.

This is my current code :

```
 List<StnRecDAL> objlist = new List<StnRecDAL>();

 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 1, FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "a", SessionYear = "2002" });
 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 2, FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "b", SessionYear = "2003" });
 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 3, FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "c", SessionYear = "2004" });
 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 4, FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "d", SessionYear = "2005" });
 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 5, FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "e", SessionYear = "2006" });
 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 6, FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "f", SessionYear = "2007" });
 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 7, FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "g", SessionYear = "2008" });
 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 8, FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "h", SessionYear = "2009" });
 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 9, FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "i", SessionYear = "20010" });
 objlist.Add(new StnRecDAL { RollNo = 10,FirsName = "ali", LastName = "helo", ClassName = "j", SessionYear = "20011" });`
```

Suggestions and guidance on how to proceed here are appreciated.

Comment: List<StnRecDAL> objlist = new List<StnRecDAL>();

Comment: Can you clarify your question(s)? it is quite confusing.BTW by "20010" and "20011" you mean "2010" and "2011" I guess :)

Comment: Try making these methods yourself and if you run into a problem, then you can try asking on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
var first = objlist.OrderBy(x => x.SessionYear).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It would not compile, and I don't think the OP would figure out to make it work, so yes. But now that it is fixed, I can (and have) easily taken my downvote off.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ extensions can help you here. You may need to read up on LINQ and lambda expressions.

```
# The ordering works below with your examples, but you might want to consider entering the dates correctly ("20011" vs "2011") and as a different datatype.
var first = objlist.OrderBy(x=>Int32.Parse(x.SessionYear)).First();
var last = objlist.OrderBy(x=>Int32.Parse(x.SessionYear)).Last();

# A list of integers
var allRollnos = objlist.OrderBy(x=>Int32.Parse(x.SessionYear)).Select(x=>x.RollNo).ToList();

# A list of StnRecDAL objects  
var studentsCalledAli = objlist.Where(x=>x.FirstName=="ali").ToList();
```